# How to use Leaflet cluster plugin

Tags: javascript, asp.net, leaflet, markers, markerclusterer

I downloaded the dist dir from leaflet at [Girhub](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)
made a site on IIS so that I can reference it but I can not even follow the examples on the demo page.

I'm using asp.net to build my site and have the following in my ASPX page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/leaflet.label.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/MarkerClusters/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="localhost/MarkerClusters/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var map = L.map('map',
                            {
                               crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
                                maxBounds: new L.LatLngBounds([-312, -180], [180, 312])
                            }).setView([0, 0], 0);

         var myIcon = L.icon({
                       iconUrl: 'http://localhost/CustomIcons/Blue.png',
                       iconSize: [20, 20],
                       shadowSize: [50, 64],
                       iconAnchor: [10, 10],
                       shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
                       popupAnchor: [0, 0]             });
```

Then this is the part I can't get:

```
         var myMarkerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup({maxClusterRadius: 120});

        //try to add markers
        var testmarker1 = L.marker(new L.LatLng(0, 0), { icon: myIcon, draggable: false });
        var testmarker2 = L.marker(new L.LatLng(10, 10), { icon: myIcon, draggable: false });

        myMarkerCluster.addLayer(testmarker1);
        myMarkerCluster.addLayer(testmarker2);

        map.addLayer(myMarkerCluster);
```

Now, the odd thing I noticed is that before I added code for the clusters, I was able to right click on the map and get a leaflet pop up with the lat,lon. I have not removed that functionality in code but now, with the cluster code addition, if I right click, then I get a regular browser context menu. I don't understand what's going on and would like to know what's missing from the marker clustering that I'm trying to accomplish. Please advise....

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is one by default, you need to add context menu to leaflet, try this

http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html

https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu